# Appium error while instantiating the object

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

This is a BeforeClass that I was creating (Java, Appium, TestNG)

private AndroidDriver driver;

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "1.7.1");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "9NLJA17619012618");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".activity.LaunchActivity");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.aaa.app");     
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.2");
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(url,desiredCapabilities);
}
```

(I know there is a mix of MobileCapabilityType and others without that format, but that i not the point I think)

And then a bunch of @Test

This error appeared:

```
Failed tests:   setUp(tests.TestShop): 
class io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver has interface io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver as super class
```

Any Clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add **MobileElement** or **WebElement** while initializing appium driver.

```
driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(url,desiredCapabilities);
```

Also change your **deviceName** to **udid**. Also make sure your **appActivity** is correct.

Your code must be like following:

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Any name");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("udid", "9NLJA17619012618");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".activity.LaunchActivity");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.aaa.app");     
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.2");
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(url,desiredCapabilities);
}
```